# Python 2.7 generic event loop

Tags: python-2.7, events, automation, modbus

I'm working on project where i could automate process of adjusting frequency for power inverter using modbus RTU protocol depending on the external sensor readings. I managed to setup network and communicate using MinimalModbus module.

However I wanted to use some 'events' mechanism which would handle modbus and sensor both. Problem is that most of modules / frameworks i found so far were for web servers / clients or for multithreading which i hardly need. My question: is there any 'generic' event modul / mechanism in python i can use regardless of application?